# How to display a frontend CiviMember page?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, forms

I have a profile set up with standard membership fields which I want to display as a front-end page in WordPress.  The profile is enabled and set up as a standalone for.

Problem: on the WordPress page when I try to embed the form the profile is not listed. Are there any dependencies for CiviMember?
I'm on Civi 4.6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to create a contribution page first and then test the contribution page by embedding against wordpress page

Once I did face similar issue - word press needs a contribution page to be created as a base - please give a try and test

If everything works fine with contribution page then try embedding your standalone profile that should work

If it fails let me know. so i will investigate more - thanks